# java error String not applicable for the arguments (List<String>)

Tags: java, string, list, arraylist

Hi I keep getting the following error:

> The method `setOfficeCode(String)` in the type UnitForm is not applicable for the arguments (`List<String>`)

The java code I have is:

```
public static void main(String[] args)   
   {   
       UnitForm uform = (UnitForm) form;

      List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();   

      lines.add("Once upon a midnight dreary");   
      lines.add("While I pondered weak and weary");   
      lines.add("Over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten lore");   

      String[] linesArr = lines.toArray(new String[lines.size()]);   

      for (String line : linesArr)   
      {   
         System.out.println(line);   
      }  

      uform.setOfficeCode(lines);
   }
```

I am trying to output what is contained in lines to a formbean in my jsp and if I convert setOfficeCode to a list what i see on my jsp is coming out with [] around it like [Over many a quaint and curious volume of forgotten lore, Hi, Bye] and I don't want the brackets to appear around the data on the jsp and i would like to break them up into separate lines instead of a whole string so that hi is on a new line and bye is on a new line etc.

Comment: As a side note. you can use the for each construct on a list (or any `Iterable`). You don't need to extract the array, first.

Comment: Why are you converting the list to an array? You can iterate over a list using the exact same syntax as what you're already using to iterate over the array.

Answer (score 2):

Your `setOfficeCode` expects a String as parameter and your giving it a list of Strings. Either change the `setOfficeCode` definition so it accepts a list, or pass only one String from your list at the method call.

Plus you don't need the array conversion as you can also do:

```
for (String line : lines)   
{   
   System.out.println(line);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

setOfficeCode{String input) 
is not equal to 
setOfficeCode(List input).

The error tells you exactly and explicitly what is wrong.

So, you problem is actually one of not understanding how your code works.

What you need to do is prepare your data before you output it in proper HTML format, or modify your JSP to handle the list instead of just a string.

Simplest way to do this would use commons-lang library (which is likely already in your class path) and do something like:

`uform.setOfficeCode(StringUtils.join(lines, "<br/>"));`